# Multiple images validation is not working - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, validation, eloquent

I am validating multiple images, but the validation is not working. I googled a lot but no answer is working for me. I am stucked.
**Here is the code (Blade file):**

```
<div class="form-row mb-4 d-none">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control adForm-fileInput d-none" multiple />
</div>
{{-- Triggering the input file --}}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light adForm-uploadBtn mb-4">
    Upload Images
</button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        // ...
        'images' => 'required',
        'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        // ...
    ]);

    // ... All Inputs requests

    $files = [];
    if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
        $images = $request->file('images');
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $name = Str::random(30) . $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);  
            $files[] = $name;
        }
    }
    $files = json_encode($files);

    // Ads::insert();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your ad has been created!');
}
```

I am uploading `jpg` images, but i am getting this error:

```
The images.0 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
The images.1 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
The images.2 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
The images.3 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
```

**My form:**

```
<form action="{{ route('routeName') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="adForm">
                @csrf
//...
```

Error should not be generated because i am uploading `jpg/png` images and error should be in 1 line, It's repeating. Please help me to figure it out. I am stuck

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your code at first glance, what does your form look like exactly? Did you add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to the opening form tag in HTML?

Comment: Yes, it's already added to my form. I am also confused about this, it should work, but it is not working

Comment: I have recreated your code, for me it is working. What happens if you upload `png` or another accepted filetype? What happens when you remove the mime type altogether? Perhaps you can share your entire form in your question so we can check if that is causing any error?

Comment: Make sure, your form method is not GET

Comment: If i upload `png/jpg/jpeg`, I am getting this error `The images.0 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
The images.1 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
The images.2 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.
The images.3 must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg.`

Comment: @sta no no, my form is `post` method

Comment: It is working for me locally. Do you have other local projects where uploading works? Perhaps you should increase the `upload_max_filesize ` and the `post_max_size` in your php.ini? If there is no issue there, I would advise removing all other fields from your form and request validation and see if there are any conflicts between inputs.

Comment: Which laravel version you are using? I faced the same error after upgrade laravel 8 (when 8 was launched). But the error fixed on the next release https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/35417

Comment: as @EricLandheer mentioned already - please share your entire form.

Comment: I've tested everything, but it's not working. Now, i did this with some changes and it's working for me now. I am posting the answer

Comment: @sta I am using the latest version, installed the project tomorrow.

Comment: I think this only happens with PHP 7.x. I am having the same issue. ".0 must be a file of type: jpg, png, svg, gif, bmp, tiff, video/avi, video/mpeg, video/quicktime."

Comment: @TGR I have solved it, you can check my answer, i have posted it

Comment: I fixed the issue by just changing mimetype to mime and adding nullable. $this->validate([
            'media.*' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,bmp,mp4,avi,mpg,mpeg|max:'.(1024*250),
        ]);

Comment: That's good....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the `mimes` is not working for me, but i find another solution.
I am just validating `max file size and required` in `laravel validator`, but for the `image type`, i am checking types seperately in the `foreach loop` like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'condition' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'price' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required',
        // Images validation except mimes
        'images' => 'required',
        'images.*' => 'max:2048'
    ]);

    // Extensions to check
    $allowedfileExtension = ['jpeg','jpg','png'];

    $files = [];
    if ($request->hasfile('images')) {
        $images = $request->file('images');
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            // Getting image extension
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);
            // Checking the image extension
            if (!$check) {
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Images must be png, jpeg or jpg!');
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
    $files = json_encode($files);

    //.. Insert function

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Your ad has been created!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->validate([
    // ...
    'images' => 'required',
    'images.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    // ...
]);
try changing to

 $request->validate([
    // ...
    'images' => 'required',
    'images.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
    // ...
]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).